# Where is AOSP surfaceflinger initiated?

Tags: java, android, android-source

[SurfaceFlinger](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/surfaceflinger-windowmanager) is essential in Android graphics rendering. I ve researched and found some code about surfaceflinger. This is its main: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/services/surfaceflinger/main_surfaceflinger.cpp

I couldnt find anything related to starting `surfaceflinger` on `init.rc`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/rootdir/init.rc

I ve found here: https://proandroiddev.com/how-android-boot-up-9864376d911c that surfaceflinger is started by `SystemServer`. So I found `SystemServer` source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java but I saw no mention of `SurfaceFlinger/surfaceflinger` or `Surface Flinger`

There is a `surfaceflinger.rc` file in the Surface Flinger directory but I couldn t find any file that includes it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/services/surfaceflinger/surfaceflinger.rc

Where is the `surfaceflinger` service started in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a surfaceflinger.rc file in the Surface Flinger directory but I couldn t find any file that includes it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/services/surfaceflinger/surfaceflinger.rc

It is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/services/surfaceflinger/Android.bp#253 `init_rc:["surfaceflinger.rc"]`:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "surfaceflinger",
    defaults: ["libsurfaceflinger_binary"],
    init_rc: ["surfaceflinger.rc"],
    srcs: [":surfaceflinger_binary_sources"],
    shared_libs: [
        "libsurfaceflinger",
        "libSurfaceFlingerProp",
    ],
}
```

Comment: yes but who uses `surfaceflinger.rc`? `init.rc` does not include it

Comment: surfaceflinger.rc is put in /system/etc/init/ and that whole folder gets loaded by /system/etc/init/hw/init.rc

Check the readme here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/core/init/

Comment: ```init.rc``` doesn't include it but build system puts it to ```/etc/init``` folder which is handled by ```init``` process.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I based by comment on README, and I mis-understood what it said.
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/core/init/init.cpp;l=309?q=file%20init.cpp